# StackNavigator and TabNavigaor is deprecated in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

In my project, after updating node modules, react navigation showed some issues. In the console it says,
*The tabBarBottom is deprecated. Use react-navigation-tabs package.
stackNavigator function name is deprecated. Use createStackNavigator
tabNavigator is deprecated. Use createBottomTabNavigator*

```
import React from "react";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { TabNavFooter } from "./TabNavFooter";
import { SIGNIN_KEY, SIGNUP_KEY } from "../config/routeKeys";
import {
  SignupScreen,
  SigninScreen,
  MainFeedScreen,
  CommentScreen,
  SharePostScreen
} from "../screens";

export const Routes = StackNavigator({
  mainfeed: { screen: TabNavFooter },
  signin: { screen: SigninScreen },
  signup: { screen: SignupScreen },
  comments: { screen: CommentScreen },
  sharePost: { screen: SharePostScreen }
});


import React from "react";
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from "react-navigation";
import { ClickableImage, ClickableIcon } from "../mixing/UI";
import TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES from "../config/tabNavImgs";
import { Image } from "react-native";

import {
  MainFeedScreen,
  WorkoutScreen,
  VideosScreen,
  ChatScreen,
  ProfileMainScreen
} from "../screens";

export const TabNavFooter = TabNavigator(
  {
    mainfeed: { screen: MainFeedScreen },
    workout: { screen: WorkoutScreen },
    video: { screen: VideosScreen },
    chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    profile: { screen: ProfileMainScreen }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let imageSource;

        if (routeName === "mainfeed") {
          imageSource =
            TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES[
              `${focused ? "mainfeedActive" : "mainfeedInactive"}`
            ];
        } else if (routeName === "workout") {
          imageSource =
            TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES[
              `${focused ? "workoutActive" : "workoutInactive"}`
            ];
        } else if (routeName === "video") {
          imageSource =
            TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES[
              `${focused ? "videoActive" : "videoInactive"}`
            ];
        } else if (routeName === "chat") {
          imageSource =
            TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES[`${focused ? "chatActive" : "chatInactive"}`];
        } else if (routeName === "profile") {
          imageSource =
            TAB_NAVIGATOR_IMAGES[
              `${focused ? "profileActive" : "profileInactive"}`
            ];
        }

        return (
          <Image
            source={imageSource}
            style={{
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
              tintColor: tintColor,
              marginBottom: 0
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "blue",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    },
    swipeEnabled: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    animationEnabled: false
  }
);
```

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to upgrade in `react-navigation` version. you have probably upgraded to v2 of the package.

They have documentation for that version but still not complete and lack in some minute details. you can see the doc in this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

the configuration differs between v1 and v2. you could manage to get v2 work with some difficulties.  you can ask specific difficulties you face in that process here or in some other question. But if you find still tough, you can move back to lower version which is well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I go back to the previous version?

Comment: Using the latest package is recommended as it will have some bug fixes of the previous version and compatibility improvements with the other latest and upgraded packages. If you have made up your mind to go back of this version then follow as below:

`react-navigation` v1.5.11 - has the methods that you are using. below is the link. You have to modify the version of `react-navigation` in package.json and do `npm install` or `yarn`

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/v1.5.11/src

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply

Answer (score 5):

Replace `StackNavigator` with `createStackNavigator`. And `TabNavigator` with `createBottomTabNavigator`.

`TabBarBottom` I have not used yet, but it looks like it was put into its own package called `react-navigation-tabs` that needs to be installed and pulled from there instead.